# MYSQL & PHP No issue connecting with database but issue when posting into the DB

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'testdatabase`.`newuserformtable' (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Title`)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

I've tried everything and I still get this error message:

```
Connected successfullyError: INSERT INTO 'testdatabase`.`newuserformtable`(`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Title`) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''testdatabase`.`newuserformtable' (`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Title`) VALUES ' at line 1
```

Comment: if you zoom in you can see you are mixing single quotes with backticks. Go with the backticks. In the testdatabase newuserformtable area

Comment: this should help you, `$sql = "INSERT INTO testdatabase.newuserformtable (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Title`)VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with your single quotes (') and back-ticks (`) in your query. Try using this below, I could not put it in comment

```
INSERT INTO `testdatabase`.`newuserformtable` ...
```

Comment: It would help to expand on your answer so it's not just a "here is the code" answer.

Comment: ok, done, I had thought that the earlier poster mentioned the issue so it would be enough, on hindsight, still better to include more information as you have rightly put.

Answer (score 1):

Database name or table name should not be considered as a string.

so the sql should be :

```
INSERT INTO testdatabase.newuserformtable (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Title`)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems error with single quote you mixed with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `testdatabase`.`newuserformtable' (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Title`)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "INSERT INTO `testdatabase`.`newuserformtable' (`First Name`,`Last Name`,`Title`)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

write like this problem with your quotes.....and also checkdatatype and length
if there is another error post your error

Answer (score 0):

You used a single quote(`'`) instead of a backtick(`` ` ``) on the database and table name.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `testdatabase`.`newuserformtable`
            (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Title`)
        VALUES
            ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `testdatabase`.`newuserformtable'
       (`First Name`,`Last Name`, `Title`)
       VALUES 
       ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

if ($res) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer works and what the code does. Otherwise your answer is likely to get downvoted and/or deleted